# How to apply wrap text to MSProject 2010 column programmatically?

Tags: c#, office-interop, ms-project

I have found code to set column best fit for long content. But when the cell content length is too long, while printing the MS project file the content was cut off. So to correct this issue I need to apply wrap text property to TaskName column in MS Project 2010 using C#.

**My question**

Is it possible to apply wrap text to each cell in Task name column they have multiple lines and to autofit row height?

**What I've tried**

I tried to select Task Name column alone and to apply text wrap property. But that is not successful. Till now I didn’t get any property to apply text wrapper in MS project using Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.dll in C#.